# Laravel - Как перевести секунды в день, час, минуты?

Tags: php, laravel

Хотел с помощью Carbon, но не нашёл как:

```php
$timeLeftSeconds = 3507;
```

Пример нужного результата:

```
0 дней, 0 часов, 55 минут
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10668410/4223982

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19680778/4223982

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```
$timeLeftSeconds = 3507;
$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $timeLeftSeconds . 'M'));
$interval = $dt->diff(new DateTime());
echo $interval->format('%d дней, %h часов, %i минут');
```